# Display thumbnail using defineTableAttributes for a custom Element Type

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, elementtype, custom-field

Hi,

I'm new to Craft and VERY new to plugin development.  I'd like to display a thumbnail image in my table list view and thought it would be possible to accomplish using a new Custom Element Type.  Does anybody know how to achieve this?

I have managed to output custom fields in the table using defineTableAttributes() but I can't output any related Assets - in particular their filenames. Do I need to define a relation in the ElementCriteriaModel using the defineCriteriaAttributes() function?  Can anyone explain how this is done?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I've managed to get an answer to this courtesy of Brandon Kelly.  It's much more simple than I thought.  Firstly, you do not have to specify a relatedTo parameter the defineCriteriaAttributes(). Craft takes care of this automatically.  So in order to retrieve the details of an asset in a table list view you do the following in the getTableAttributeHtml() function in your custom Element Type class:

```
$relatedAsset = $element->myAssetsField->first();
```

This simple line of code gets a related myAssetsField of your element. I'm not sure why, but this object is placed in an array...  Maybe someone can tell me why this is the case?

I then took the fist element of the array and used a the getThumbUrl() function which is really handy for quickly outputting the url to a thumbnail.  I passed a size of 60 pixels.

```
case 'myAttribute>':
{   
   if(count($relatedAsset) > 0) {
      return '<img src="'.$relatedAsset[0]->getThumbUrl(60).'">';
   }
   return '';
}
```

The result is a thumbnail in your table list!
Hope this helps others....

Comment: Nice to see this is that simple. Thanks for sharing, brasso!